# How to match commas and "and" with preg_split in PHP

Tags: php, regex, split, preg-split

I have this string:

```
Rosemary J. Harris $^{1}$, Vladislav Popkov $^{2}$ and Gunter M. Sch\"utz $^{3,}$*
```

And I would liek to split it with commas (,) or "and" string.

So, the result should be:

```
[0] -> Rosemary J. Harris $^{1}$
[1] -> Vladislav Popkov $^{2}$
[2] -> Gunter M. Sch\"utz $^{3,}$*
```

I tryied this:

```
$splitAuthors = preg_split('/[, ]+[ and ]/', $authors);
```

Which is returning:

```
[0] -> Rosemary J. Harris $^{1}$
[1] -> Vladislav Popkov $^{2}$
[2] -> nd Gunter M. Sch\"utz $^{3,}$*
```

There is the "nd" in the last array item.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not just explode?

Comment: because comma is also used in the regex expressions, like after ``M.Sch\"utz``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use character classes for this use the or seperator |

This should give you the correct output:

```
preg_split("/, | and /",$data)
```

Gives the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Rosemary J. Harris $^{1}$
    [1] => Vladislav Popkov $^{2}$
    [2] => Gunter M. Sch\"utz $^{3,}$*
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`[]` define a *character class*. These match a SINGLE character, where that character can be any of the characters in the class. So you're looking for a spot in your string where that spot contains either a space, an `a`, an `n`, or a `d`. It's NOT looking for the world "and" with spaces on either side. You probably want `( and )` instead.